# Qt Creator error during linking: Cannot specify link libraries for target

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt-creator

I am new to both Qt Creator and Cmake, and I'm trying to compile a simple program by linking to an existing library in Ubuntu, `libaspell-1.2.so.16`, which is found at `usr/lib`. So, I have a custom Cmake step in the build process, which takes the following `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(Demo-Project)

target_link_libraries(demo libaspell-1.2.so.16)

add_executable(demo demo.cpp)
```

My `demo.cpp` file is just a simple function:

```
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

However, I get the following error during compilation:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "demo" which is not built by this
  project.
```

This is such a simple program I am trying to compile that it seems like I am doing something fundamentally wrong. I have tried linking to other library files that come with Ubuntu by default, but I get the same error message.

So, is the behaviour above expected due to a simple fault of my own, or is it something more complex that I need to investigate?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the order matters, so I'd try:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(Demo-Project)

add_executable(demo demo.cpp)

target_link_libraries(demo libaspell-1.2.so.16)
```